# Docs open on select?

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files

New Linux user here. I just installed Elementary OS Juno on my MS Surfacebook. What I've noticed is that in the Files app, it REALLY wants to launch the parent app. I just have to select a document and in a second, the app is launched.

That's a bit hyper active. Is there any way to have select JUST select the file and wait for a double click to open?

Comment: I understand why you need this, but this is part of the design of eOS. Can you try it for a few days before you install the tweaks as answered below? I had the same issue with it, but now I'm used to it. :)

Comment: I'm a UX designer. Telling me to 'just get used to it' is waving a red flag in my face ;-) It's actually quite arrogant of eOS to assume that 95+% of the desktop users on the planet (Mac + Windows) are wrong. For switchers like me, forcing me into such a new behavior is not friendly at all. Finally, I've only heard a MILLION times that the beauty of Linux is that it's flexible. Not having an option to turn it off flies in the face of that core belief.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not mean to be condescending. I've been with Linux long enough to appreciate it's flexibility. :) I think the thing I was looking for in eOS was the relief that I DON'T have to configure everything like I have to in other distros. But I understand (like I did before too) that you need it. Also having to try a different things to improve the UX is what you do as a UX designer no? ;) Finally, I have heard from a lot of new people trying Linux that the community is harsh/rude. I don't want you to feel the same way. Please enjoy Linux the way you prefer to! And welcome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install elementary tweaks to adjust various settings to your liking (amongst which changing the single click behaviour). Run these commands to install it:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks 
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

Then open settings, select tweaks, go to the "files" tab and uncheck single click.

Comment: This was *exactly* what I needed thank you. As I'm new in this corner to stack overflow, I'm apparently not allowed to mark this as "this answered my question"

Comment: Actually, I can now. Marked as answered. Thank you!